# Why is the "hidden" class applied to an element BEFORE it is clicked?

Tags: javascript

This is my JS code:

```
var btn = document.querySelector("button");
btn.addEventListener("click", hide(this, true));
function hide(event, reflow) {
  if(reflow) {
    document.querySelector(".great").classList.add("hidden");
  }
}
```

Could anybody please shed some light as to why this is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@blex is correct in explaining why the function executes immediately, but the signature you have seems like you are trying to use [`Function.prototype.call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call). Here's what I suggest using:

```
btn.addEventListener('click', function(event){ hide.call(this, event, true); });
```

What this does is pass the context of the anonymous function (the `function(event){...}`) to `hide()` and sets the first two arguments `e` and `reflow` to `event` and `true`.

See [MDN `MouseEvent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent) for what sort of properties the `event` object contains.

Answer (score 6):

On the `addEventListener` line, you are executing the `hide` function immediately (by having parenthesis). You can avoid that by wrapping it with an anonymous function:

```
btn.addEventListener('click', function(){ hide(this, true); });
```

*As @Patrick Roberts said below, it might have an impact on what `this` represents. I'm not sure about that, so I'll let him or someone else explain it.*

Comment: Pretty sure it should be be `function(event){ hide.call(this, event, true); }`

Comment: @PatrickRoberts You might be right, but I'm not sure of how to back this up (about the `this, event` part). Would you mind adding this as an answer with some explanation?

Answer (score 3):

look at here.

```
btn.addEventListener('click', hide(this, true));
```

you are calling `hide(this, true)` method explicitly.
the method `addEventListener` is expecting a function reference in the second argument to call when the button the is get click. 
so you can do

```
 btn.addEventListener('click', function(){ hide(this, true));
```